# Finding number of relations on a set with 3 elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

How do I find find out how many non reflexive relations X on the set P = {1, 2, 3}?

I know $2^{n^2 - n}$ returns how many reflexive relations there on a set. Do I subtract that from something to get my result?

Comment: Quite right, you subtract that from the total number of relations.

Comment: @vadim123 how do i calculate total number of relations

Answer (score 1):

A relation on set $P$ is a subset of $P\times P$.  In this case, $|P|=3$ so $|P\times P|=9$.  Hence there are $2^9$ subsets of $P\times P$, and thus $2^9$ relations on $P$.

Comment: So I just calculate $2^9$ - $2^{n^2 - n}$ with 'n' = 3?

Answer (score -1):

Non-Reflexive relations are simply those that do not satisfy the aRa criteria for all 'a' in the corresponding set. Therefore the number of these is mostly irrelevant.

Now, **Irreflexive relations** are those relations such that for every a in the set, aRa is False. They are in stark contrast to reflexive relations.

Therefore, the number of irreflexive relations on a set of cardinality n is easily the difference of the total number of binary relations possible on the set and the total number of reflexive relations on the set.

```
=2^(n^2)-2^(n(n-1))
```